# How to go to Top of React Native Flatlist with HeaderComponent

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an app with 3 tabs(Tab A, B, C). Say Tab A has a Flatlist with ListHeaderComponent. When a user opens the app, Tab A will be shown first. Then the user can go to Tab B, Tab C. When the user comes back to Tab A, I want to scroll to top of the Flatlist (not index 0) but to the very top of header component. I tried

```
this.refs.listRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0, viewPosition: 0});
```

But it is not working. Anyone has done this before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to show the complete element code that you configured?

Comment: I can show an example:

`<FlatList
     ref="listRef"
     extraData={this.state}
     ListHeaderComponent={this.headerComponent}
     renderItem={item => (
     ...
     )}
/>`

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution:

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 });
```

Will scroll to the very top.